# IE Edge Setting not persisting

Tags: internet-explorer

I am facing a document mode problem in IE Edge. When my developer toolbar is opened then the document mode is changing to 'Edge' but whenever I am closing it and then reopening the browser the edge settings is not persisting anymore. I want permanent document mode setting to IE Edge. I am using Windows 7. Any solution?

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`

Comment: How can I apply this?

Comment: put it in your html `<head>` section. Also google it -- there's loads of info on stackoverflow and the rest of the web about X-UA-Compatible.